# Installing a perl module from CPAN on XAMPP for Windows

Tags: windows, perl, xampp, cpan

I'm pretty rusty with Perl and I don't think it's helping that I'm running it in Windows.

I'd like to install [this](http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/Config-Simple-4.59/Simple.pm) module. I tried the instructions [here](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INST) to install a CPAN module, but it fails trying to install App::cpanminus (the very first step.) I tried just running `cpan Config::Simple` and it didn't work either. In both situations, it fails with this error message:

```
Unwrapping had some problem, won't try again without force
  Had problems unarchiving. Please build manually
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
```

Does CPAN just not work from the version of Perl that's installed with XAMPP? If so, how do I upgrade it without breaking anything?

Comment: Do a `perl -v` to tell us what version you're running. Also, is this ActivePerl or Strawberry Perl?

Comment: This is the output from my XAMPP install of perl:

C:\xampp\perl\bin>perl -v

This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. manually download and unpack the distro archive
2. change into the unpacked directory
3. run `cpanm .` or `cpan .`

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP also ships with [PPM](http://search.cpan.org/~murray/PPM-2.1.8/bin/ppm.pl) in C:\xampp\perl\bin\ppm.bat which is often a more Windows friendly way to get modules for perl.

There's a step by step example of using ppm with XAMPP here: http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=26407

Many modules are already installed in C:\xampp\perl\lib and C:\xampp\perl\site\lib