# Perl and Html5 ServerSentEvents

Tags: html, perl, sleep, server-sent-events

I am trying to deploy server sent events to replace ajax long polling in my application. In perl script, the sleep is blocking the sending stream.

```
#!/opt/lampp/bin/perl
print "Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n";
 while(1){
  print "event: server-time\n";
  my $time = localtime();
  print "data: $time\n\n";
 }
```

This code works. But, with sleep it is not working. Just streaming

Instead of printing the content it keeps loading.

HTML snippet:

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function invokeSSE(){
  var source = new EventSource('test.pl');
  source.addEventListener('server-time', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('ticker').innerHTML = e.data + '<br>';
  }, false);
  source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
  alert('open');
  }, false);
  source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
  if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
  alert("Connection closed"); 
  }
  }, false);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="invokeSSE()">
 <div id="ticker" name="ticker">
  [TIME]
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

The sleep is always going to block, it is by design.

You should create an event based application for this, you could use Dancer, Mojolicious for this.

From: http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Streaming_response

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;

# Build a normal transaction
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $tx = $ua->build_tx(GET => 'http://example.com');

# Prepare body
my $body = 'Hello world!';
$tx->req->headers->content_length(length $body);

# Start writing directly with a drain callback
my $drain;
$drain = sub {
  my $content = shift;
  my $chunk   = substr $body, 0, 1, '';
  $drain      = undef unless length $body;
  $content->write($chunk, $drain);
};
$tx->req->content->$drain;

# Process transaction
$tx = $ua->start($tx);
```

Comment: Am using xampp already. How shall i deploy dancer or mojolicious with xampp

Comment: @user2943851 http://stackoverflow.com/q/7171138/223226 or check http://strawberryperl.com/