# What are the frameworks available in perl

Tags: regex, perl, testing, frameworks

Can anyone list what are the frameworks available in perl and what are used for testing and for tool development. I had lot of confusion on it. The answer would help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is *far* too broad a question.

Comment: If anyone can help me it would be fine. Because not everyone knows everything. Thanks for those who responded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some *Perl web framework*:

[Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/)

[Perl Dancer](http://perldancer.org/)

[Catalyst](https://www.perl.org/about/whitepapers/perl-webframework.html)

For more information read this: [Which Perl web framework should I use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4758009/4248931)

See the [Comparison of Perl web application frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Perl_2)